# Bootstrap tabs displaying search results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I have a simple two tab layout. First tab shows details whereas the second tab shows a search box and search results. When a user navigates to the page I wish to show the first tab however when a search is performed (from the second tab) I wish the show the page displaying the second tab.

I had tried the code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="<%= 'active' if !params[:search] %>">
    <a href="#details" data-target="#details" data-toggle="tab">Details</a>
  </li>
  <li class="<%= 'active' if params[:search] %>">
    <a href="#search" data-target="#search" data-toggle="tab">Search</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The code above displays the correct tab however not the corresponding div so if a search is performed the "Search" tab is active however the "Details" div is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I did not realise I had to set the active class for both the "li" item and the corresponding "div" item. Works now.
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tabs_pills.asp

```
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane <%= 'active' if !params[:search] %> fade in" id="details">
    ...
  </div>

  <div class="tab-pane <%= 'active' if params[:search] %>" id="search">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: helpful question and answer, I will try it.